# Browser refresh in MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have an MVC 5 application with multiple controllers and multiple views(Controller1 with action1(associated view1) and Controller2 with action2(associated view2)). I defined Controller1 and action1 as default in RouteConfig.cs. The default url I see in the address bar is when I run the applicaiton from IIS is 
   http://andem.sunquestinfo.com/dxp"
I do not see the controller or action name. I navigate to view2 and see the View2 contents and the url in the address bar remains the same. Now if I refresh the page (either by F5 or browser refresh icon) I am redirected to view1 and the url doesn't change.

I tried using custom ActionFilterAttribute, but on F5 Request.Url is
    "http://andem.sunquestinfo.com/dxp"

Please suggest why the controller and action name are not shown in the url and how I detect browser refresh.

Thank you
MA

Answer (score 0):

Well one thing for sure is you cannot detect browser refresh server side, for the server its just another request/response cycle that gets triggered.

No you dont see the controller or action when you debug the application because it navigates to the root of your site, and you have configured your routing to default to a certain controller/action when it doesnt receive this info explicitly.

As to why the url doesn't change when you navigate to view2 its hard to tell because I dont know exactly how you navigate to it